# Spring changing application behavior : from Java proxies to CGLIB proxies

Tags: spring, jhipster, cglib

The application is on the basis of JHipster.
This one integrate spring 4.2 (spring boot, spring security, spring mvc/rest, spring data jpa).
I must turn the Jhipster "framework" application from java based proxies to CGLIB proxies. It is easy to configure in "DatabaseConfiguration.java" setting :

@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)

So now I can use the implementation instead of the interface with @Inject annotation. I need this.

The problem comes with whole JHipster application not parameterized for this at basis. So when I start application (which start well), I've got NullPointException in spring security framework when I attempt to log in after login form filled (click button), because of this CGLIB configuration. (If I rollback this, it works like before).

What I need to "refactor" in Jhispter so to be able to use CGLIB in whole application.

Thanks for your help.

Stack trace error when log in through GUI :

```
2016-05-11 14:35:21.837 DEBUG 1528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Application Event Raised: AuditApplicationEvent
2016-05-11 14:35:21.837 DEBUG 1528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Application Event Raised: AuthenticationSuccessEvent
2016-05-11 14:35:21.837 DEBUG 1528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Application Event Raised: SessionFixationProtectionEvent
2016-05-11 14:35:21.837 DEBUG 1528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Application Event Raised: SessionFixationProtectionEvent
2016-05-11 14:35:21.837 DEBUG 1528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.t.s.CustomPersistentRememberMeServices : Did not send remember-me cookie (principal did not set parameter 'null')
2016-05-11 14:35:21.853 ERROR 1528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.loginSuccess(AbstractRememberMeServices.java:273) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:323) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:245) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.tess2i.web.filter.CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]

2016-05-11 14:35:21.853 DEBUG 1528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Application Event Raised: ServletRequestHandledEvent
2016-05-11 14:35:21.853 DEBUG 1528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Application Event Raised: ServletRequestHandledEvent
2016-05-11 14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- CGLIB is already working with JHipster/Spring Boot. Try generating a service without an implementation, you will see it works.
  As you say you want to directly use implementations instead of interfaces, there seems to be a misunderstanding here, as we do it all the time in the project (in fact that's our default usage of Spring Beans).
- Indeed you can force having CGLIB proxies with `proxyTargetClass = true` instead of JDK proxies, for when you have interfaces, but technically this shouldn't make any difference to you. I would even argue it's better to have JDK proxies for debugging, but that's up to you, of course. My point is that this shouldn't trigger any error, like you have. I don't understand how this could trigger a NPE in AbstractRememberMeServices anyway, this looks like another issue to me.

Comment: Ok thanks you for explanations. I managed to make it works doing a service implementation extending another abstract class which this latter implements the service interface. Then I can inject the implementation. This is my solution, maybe not the better but it works.